# Limiting behavior of tail probability of gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Given a standard Gaussian vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$, that is $Z \sim N(0, I_d)$, can we specify a function $R(\cdot)$ and constant $K$ such that :

$$\mathbb{P}(||Z||_2 > t) R(t) \to K$$ as $t \to \infty$?

I'm not certain what to make of this exercise. Are $R(\cdot)$ and $K$ to be exact or unique or are there multiple valid choices?

I was thinking of using subexponential tail bounds (since $||Z||^2_2 = \sum_1^d Z_i^2 \sim \chi(d)$ and is sub-exponential $SE(4d,4)$) which would give us
$$\mathbb{P}(||Z||_2^2 > t^2 + d) \leq \exp{\frac{-t^2}{8}} $$

which would allow me to take $R(t) = \exp{\frac{+t^2}{8}}$ and $K=1$.

Is this sound as an approach? If not, what would be a better direction to proceed? If it is a sound approach, are there better ways to go about this?

Edit: for $d=1$, the standard univariate gaussian, I am familiar with the following result:
For $t > 0$:
$$\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(|Z|>t)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{1}{t} e^{-t^{2} / 2}} = \dfrac{2\mathbb{P}(Z>t)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{1}{t} e^{-t^{2} / 2}} \to 2$$

as $t \to \infty$.

So would $K=2$ and $R(t) =\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{1}{t} e^{-t^{2} / 2}\right)^{-1}$ (or something of this form) be better candidates?

Comment: Why not $R(t) = \frac{K}{P(||Z||_2 > t)}$?